# Python 3.8 Downloading Packages/Modules error using PIP

Tags: python-3.8

I am trying to install numpy but it is giving this error please help what should I do ?

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 331, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 480, in prepare_linked_requirement
    local_path = unpack_url(
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 282, in unpack_url
    return unpack_http_url(
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 158, in unpack_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 303, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 160, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 15, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 564, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 529, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\cutea\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

[image]

Comment: Check if you can ping the host you are downloading from: `$ ping files.pythonhosted.org`

Comment: Nothing Happened request timed out what should i do now?

Comment: Then you don't have a network connection where you can access the site. If you are behind a corporate proxy, then ask your help desk or cloud adoption team. Otherwise, check your network security settings and ensure that there aren't any firewall rules that prevent egress. Of you cannot reach the site over the network, then you cant download anything

Answer (score 2):

Look directly at the last line ：
Read timed out

Connect to wifi or faster internet and try again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

my internet connection was poor then i got this error. Then i tried it with faster connection and it worked for me...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).